# Vue.js - Element UI - Dynamic rules validation form

Tags: vuejs2

I'm using `vue-js2.3` and `element-ui`.

I would like to define the validation rules of my form dynamically

#### Example

https://jsfiddle.net/cgL6y9kq/

#### Problem

The `required` is not dynamically defined by `phoneMandatory`

#### Questions

How can I change the attribute on an existing rule dynamically?
How can I add or remove rules dynamically ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You have your `rules` property in the component's `data` method. This means it will not updated based on changes to other data properties.

You should use a computed property for `rules` instead:

```
computed: {
  rules() {
    return { 
      phone: [{ 
        required: this.phoneMandatory, 
        message: 'Please input phone', 
        trigger: 'blur' 
      }]
    }
  }
},
```

Now, when `this.phoneMandatory` updates, so will the component's `rules` property.

[Here's a working fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/rtb0h7z0/)

Comment: you're a genius